# Is there a way to click a hyperlink using $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click(); or something similar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing an iOS app that has an offscreen uiwebview, and to be able to interact with it, I need to simulate mouse clicks in JavaScript. I've managed to use `$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();` to be able to click on JavaScript buttons, but I need a way to be able to click on a hyperlink using some kind of coordinate. Is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you try `$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();`?

Comment: it doesnt do anything on a hyperlink it seems

Comment: Just nothinh happens? No errors? Have you checked the console?

Comment: just checked now, no errors or anything. I think that function can only click on objects that have some kind of javascript function attached to them, so they will have like `onclick="function()"` that will do something, not just a plain hyperlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can initiate a click event on `<a>` links by the following code:

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(event);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7herR/2/

Not sure about browser compatibilities, but tested on Firefox at least.

Comment: ah, this looks promising. let me test it out

Comment: I think it's semantically identical to `.click()` - I don't have time to check the jQuery source just now, though.

Comment: Strangely, using jQuery's `.click` or `.trigger` doesn't work on links, but DOM `.dispatchEvent` works.

Comment: @AlvinWong yes this is strange, but good to know, because now i wont need to check if i have clicked on a hyperlink or something else, this is much more like a normal mouse click

Comment: curious - jQuery doesn't actually seem to call `dispatchEvent()`, it looks like it just triggers jQuery-registered handlers and DOM0 `.onXXX` handlers.  I suspect it'll fail to call any handlers registered using `addEventHandler()`.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to get a reference to the element, and just call `window.location = $("a").attr("href");` or `window.open($("a").attr("href"));`

http://jsfiddle.net/RaT6r/ for an example using your own method

Comment: +1 I agree that using the `window.location` to follow the `href` is a good idea.

Comment: The problem is "Activating" the anchor tag in the first place. OP isn't clicking the actual tag.
-1 since this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: i need to be able to "click" the link via a coordinate on the page though. how the app works is it will get the coordinate of the touch on the screen and map them to the offscreen webview, so i need a way of "clicking" the hyperlink at a coordinate.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote... and I don't understand your problem Fonix. You have already answered your own question, with the usage of elementFromPoint you can acquire a DOM node on the page. If you are looking for a way to resolve to that url once you have acquired a reference, use the method I suggested.

Comment: ah yes, sorry im very new to javascript, so i didnt understand what you meant, the example you gave seems to do the trick, except its opening in a popup window, if i use the window.locatio, will that open in the same page?

Comment: @Fonix Yes, `window.location` redirects the current page to the URL specified, while `window.open` opens a new window/tab with the URL specified.

Comment: Whilst this answer appears to address the OP's requirement, there could well be _other_ JS code attached to the `<a>` link.  It would be useful to establish the _right_ way of triggering all event handlers associated with that element and figure out why the OP's code didn't work.

Comment: Yea, window.location opens in self. You could also change the target on the anchor tag to _self. The fiddle I uploaded pulls the target attribute so that you could control which window the href opens in on an anchor-by-anchor basis...

Comment: @Alnitak ill have to come up with a way to determine what ive clicked on, if its a hyperlink, use the .attr("href") on the element, otherwise just do a normal click. I think that would do.

Comment: @FarisM I want to lift my downvote, could you make an edit? I misunderstood the answer.